# Properties of relations on Z

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

$$R_3 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}|\frac{x-y}{5} \in \mathbb{Z}\} $$
$$R_4 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}|x > y \} $$

I need to know which one is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive and if they're an equivalence relation, what are their equivalence classes?

For now, I think $R_3$ and $R_4$ are antisymetric, but I don't know if there're reflexive or transitive.

And, I don't know if I'm right to think that.

Comment: Please tell us what progress you've made.

Comment: The first step to, e.g., seeing if $R_3$ is symmetric is to write out what it means to be reflexive along with what it means to be related by $R_3$. Have you gotten that far, or is that what you're having trouble with?

Comment: Because I don't really understant your approach. I presume I didn't go so far.

Comment: $ R_3$ reflexive, anti symmetric , transitive. $ R_4$ not reflexive,  anti symmetric,  transitive. Both relations are not equivalence relation.

Comment: @mwomath Thanks!